# AJAX object data formats? E.g.: Pagination

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-structures, datagrid

Is there a "generic" expected data structure to hold data for a datagrid? I'm using JSON something like this right now and it's working well...

```
{ 
  "pagination": {
     "currentPage": 4,
     "totalPages": 8
  },
  "headers":["id","name","postal_code","email"],
  "data":[
     ["12345","Tran Smith","55505","tran@example.org"],
     ... more data rows here ...
   ]

}
```

But I get the nagging feeling it could be better, more reusable.

There are many libraries that have datagrid style components, and it would be great to see different examples of how this is handled.

It would be useful if for whatever reason a library got out of date if we could re-use the same AJAX for different projects which use different libraries.

Comment: If you're asking if there's a common data structure that would fit most libraries, the answer would be "no". Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that's what I'm asking, and it's pretty clear the answer is that there is not, given the lack of answers. Thanks.